# How To Give Widgets Individual ID's or Classes?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

On my wordpress installation, I created a new theme for a new page template I created. However, when I goto create new widgets, each widget automatically gets the class of "textwidget". I have two different styles I have for widgets that require different styles, so I'm not too sure how to give each indivudal widget a different class or to label them differently?

Anyone know how to do this?

Here's a page from my site with the 2 widgets: http://www.simonsayswebsites.com/how-we-get-you-more-customers/

You can see each one is within a widget that has the same class name.

This is what I added to my page functions.php to add the widget:

```
    if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'sidebarpage',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="sidebarpage">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
));
}
```

And here's the snippet from the page template itself for it to display:

```
<?php /* Widgetized sidebar */
    if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebarpage') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>
```

I could make it using different widgetized areas, but want to learn about having individual widget styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaking `name` and `id`.

Also, in `before_widget`, you shouldn't declare a fixed ID, in your site both Widgets have the same ID and that's... no good.

If you follow the example in the Codex, your widget will receive an unique ID and a relevant class.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

#### Default usage

```
<?php $args = array(
    'name'          => __( 'Sidebar name', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'unique-sidebar-id',
    'description'   => '',
    'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' ); ?>
```

Comment: awesome dude.. i got it to work! thanks for pointing out what i was doing wrong. i actually grabbed the code above from some random blog that showed how to add widgets to your page.. i had no idea i was doing it wrong. thanks again man!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @sab, *The Codex is your friend, consult the Codex* :o)